# Computer software: Send to any folder option

Tags: send-to

Years ago there was a program called "Where" or "Where to" or something like that which added a "folder" option, but not as a fixed path to a certain pre-selected folder but allowing you to write or locate the name of any other folder in your system, or even create a new folder on the spot.
For some reason that program ceased to be available, and since then I have been unable to find another which allows such an "open" option instead of a fixed shortcut. Can you help, please?

Comment: Which OS? You must include such information in a question like this.

Comment: Oh, for [RSTS/E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSTS/E)???

Comment: [Send To Toys: Enhance the Send To system context menu](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/send-to-toys-for-windows)?